# How to find a large $U_n$ from a recurrence formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am studying sequences as part of A-Level Maths and we are doing the recurrence formula type questions.  Say it is $u_{n+1} = u_n - u_{n-1}$.  And you were asked to find the values of $u_{13}, u_{63}, u_{89}$ .

How would you do this without knowing the numbers in the sequence before?

Comment: I reformatted your question.  Please check to make sure I didn't change your meaning.  Also, if you click on "edit" you can see the syntax involved.  Here is a good tutorial on formatting:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

Let $u_1=\color{red}{a},u_2=\color{green}{b}$. Then, we have
$$u_3=b-a$$
$$u_4=(b-a)-b=-a$$
$$u_5=-a-(b-a)=-b$$
$$u_6=-b-(-a)=a-b$$
$$u_7=a-b-(-b)=\color{red}{a}$$
$$u_8=a-(a-b)=\color{green}{b}$$